# [UICTFont isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent

Tags: ios11, xcode9

I am facing this issue with Xcode 9 and ios 11 only. Not even getting a back trace of where it is occuring. The app just crashes by giving me this error.

Answer (score 2):

When you describe a `key-value` pair for `NSFontAttributeName` with `NSDictionary` and if you attempt to set object as a key and key as an object, it will crash with `[UICTFont isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent error`.

An example in `Objective-C`:

```
NSDictionary *attributedDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:NSFontAttributeName forKey:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15]];
```

In the example, the attribute name is set for the object and the object is set for the key. So you must fix it.

It will crash with error what you have.

Answer (score 0):

I have a smilier issue on iOS 11, I was using

self.title = @"Select places";

in viewDidLoad to set the title, that was causing an issue when I add a search bar to NavigatonBar the crash need to further debug to root cause.

Hope this helps for debugging the issue in your case.